# how i can add multiple values in one variable in postman?

Tags: postman, postman-collection-runner

i need to run only one request with 4 sets of data, rest all requests i want to run one time so iteration is not an option for me. the request is get and i want to pass multiple values in one of the parameter of get request. want to run script for those many times like if 4 values in variable script should run 4 times. How i can add 4 values in one global parameter? secondly how to later use that parameter to run that many times?

```
pm.globals.set('my_var', JSON.stringify('["iphone", "ipad"]'))

for ( i=1; i<= 4; i++)
{

   console.log (JSON.parse(pm.globals.get('my_var'))[0].value);
}
```

This is returning me [ as value as [ is present at that point but i want to make it read whole value which is iphone. Please guide

Answer (score 0):

This works for me:

```
pm.globals.set('my_var',('["iphone", "ipad"]'));

for (i=1; i<= 4; i++)
{
   console.log (JSON.parse(pm.globals.get('my_var'))[0]);
}
```